# how to subsample a numpy array every 10 elements of 3 chose elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21...]
```

and I want to first choose the elements 7, 8, 9 and afterwards choose every 10 items of these 3 elements to form a new array

```
b=[7 8 9 17 18 19 27 28 29 ....]
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: Please share with us your attempts to show us how did you try to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reshaping to convert it to 2-D, then select columns and finally flatten it back to 1-D:

```
b = a.reshape(-1,10)[:,7:10].flatten()
```

And if your array’s shape is not a multiplier of 10, you can either crop it or pad it with zeros first and then remove extra zeros from selection.

How to crop first:

```
a = a[:a.size//10*10]
```

And padding with zero:

```
a = a.resize((a.size//10+1)*10)
```

Removing extra unwanted selected zeros is another cropping.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a list comprehension and boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(123)
mask = [True if x%10 in [7,8,9] else False for x in a]
b = a[mask]
```